# Find $X$ such that $ \left\| A \odot X - B \right\|_F^2$ is minimized

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

Find $X$ such that $ \left\| A \odot X - B   \right\|_F^2$ is minimized, where $\odot$ denotes elementwise multiplication (or Hadamard product).

My solution is as follows as:
Let $f(X) =  \left\| A \odot X - B   \right\|_F^2$. Then, the gradient is $\nabla f(x) = 2 A \odot \left( A \odot X - B \right) $. Thereafter, setting $\nabla f(x) = 0$ and solving for $X$, which reads
\begin{align}
X = \left(A \odot B\right) \oslash \left( A \odot A \right),
\end{align}
where $\oslash $ denotes elementwise division.

> Is my solution correct?

Comment: Your computation of the gradient is wrong.

Comment: Your solution is correct and can be simplified to $\,X = A\oslash B\;$

Comment: @greg thank you for the confirmation and further simplification

Comment: Looks like you swapped $A$ and $B$ since my comment, so now $\,X=B\oslash A\;$

Comment: @greg Oh yes. Thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct as confirmed by greg but I started writing this before they replied and I don't want it to go to waste.

Let's compute the gradient of $f(X) = \|B\odot X-A\|^2$:

$$\mathrm{d}f = \mathrm{d}\left(h\circ g\right) = 2\langle B\odot X-A,\mathrm{d}g\rangle$$

where $h(X) = \frac{1}{2}\|X\|^2$ and $g(X) = B\odot X-A$. Then

$$dg = \mathrm{d}(B\odot X) - \mathrm{d}A = B\odot \mathrm{d}X.$$

So

$$\mathrm{d}f = 2\langle B\odot X-A,B\odot \mathrm{d}X\rangle = 2\langle B\odot(B\odot X-A),\mathrm{d}X\rangle.$$

The gradient is thus

$\nabla f(X) = 2B\odot(B\odot X-A).$

Setting this equal to $0$ gives

$$2B\odot(B\odot X-A) = 0\Leftarrow B\odot X = A \Leftarrow X = A\oslash B$$